# MYSQL slow_query_log with log_queries_not_using_indexes logging almost all queries

Tags: sql, mysql

MYSQL version 8.0.34 with the following variables enabled:

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON
slow_query_log = ON
```

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `countries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `countries`
  MODIFY `id` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=69;
COMMIT;
```

Data:

```
id | country
1  | Afghanistan
2  | Albania
3  | Algeria
4  | Andorra
5  | Angola
```

Query:

```
SELECT id, country AS country_name FROM countries
```

Explain output `EXPLAIN SELECT id, country FROM countries`:

```
id | select_type | table     | partitions  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | countries | NULL        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  63 | 100.00 | NULL
```

Logged query:

```
# Time: 2023-10-10T14:57:36.980019Z
# User@Host: db_user[db_user] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:  2710
# Query_time: 0.000140  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 63  Rows_examined: 63
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1696863456;
select id, country AS country_name from `countries`;
```

The `id` is primary and auto incremented so this is strange.

Should I ignore such query logs or there is an issue with the structure or the query?

Answer (score 1):

The EXPLAIN report you show includes the column `type: ALL` which indicates it is reading the query with a table-scan. This does not use an index. The query has no filtering conditions or sorting clause, so there's no use for it to employ an index.

It's possible that in any application, there are many such queries that naturally do not use an index, but it is by design.

This means the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` option is pretty limited in its usefulness. It may cause a lot of queries to be logged without giving you actionable information. It might also log queries that need some attention for optimization, but they tend to be lost in the log among many entries for queries that do not require attention.

I don't typically enable `log_queries_not_using_indexes`, except temporarily if I'm trying to diagnose a specific problem query.